# CIDissolveTransition problems. kCIAttributeTypeTime only works with 0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, core-image

Core Image Aficionados: I have a conundrum, my CIDissolveTransition only works when the inputTime attribute is 0.0. it crashes with any value between 0.0 and 1.0, including 1.0. It only works with 0.0. Here is my code:

```
CIFilter* overlayFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDissolveTransition" keysAndValues: 
@"inputImage", photoImage,
@"inputTargetImage", muralOverlay,
@"inputTime", 1.0,
nil];
```

I have a photo and a mural image and I am trying to make the photo look like a mural by overlaying the mural on top of it. Any ideas for other filters would be helpful as well.

Thanks,

-Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` is the default value, you have to set it as `NSNumber`, try with:

```
CIFilter* overlayFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDissolveTransition" keysAndValues: 
@"inputImage", photoImage,
@"inputTargetImage", muralOverlay,
@"inputTime", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0],
nil];
```

Check the [Core Image Filter Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Perfect! That was it! Unfortunately, it's really, really slow. I wanted to tie this value up to a slider, but the slider lags when it is moved and takes probably 20 seconds to update. Any ideas for speeding that up? Thanks again!

Comment: Use Metal view to draw ciimage